# How do you add Values to each row of the Dataframe Using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

How do I add data to each row of my dataframe.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

People = namedtuple('People',['id','name'])

dictionary = {1: People(1,'Rodger'), 2: People(2,'Betty'), 3: People(1,'Susie')}

keys = list(map(int, dictionary.keys())) # [1, 2, 3]

for k in dictionary:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': keys, 'name': dictionary[k].name})

print(df)
```

It doesn't add each name to a row that corresponds to its id. It fills every row of the name column with the value 'Rodger'. Why is this?

```
[current output]

id:     name:
1       Susie
2       Susie
3       Susie

[desired output]

id:     name:
1       Rodger
2       Betty
3       Susie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because you are overriding the dataframe at every iteration:

```
for k in dictionary:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': keys, 'name': dictionary[k].name}) # override using all keys but next name in sequence
```

A solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': keys, 'name': [item.name for item in dictionary.values()]})
```

Comment: Hey, the code runs for me. Thanks very much, I need it to work with a dictionary of People not a list. I tried your method and it didn't work.

Comment: It can't run. pd.Dataframe does not exist, for example. It is pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my code. It should compile now.

Comment: your code works when I use a list, but I needed it to work with a Dictionary. @pceccon